# How to create more than 1048576 rows using JAVA with POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I´m trying to create with POI a long excel file but I can no do that because the limit is 1048576

The version of POI that I use is 3.15 thank you.

In the following code the limit was 2.347.303 and the number of columns its 20:

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(3000);
wb.setCompressTempFiles(true);

for (int rownum = 0; rownum < this.limit; rownum++) {
 if (rownum == 0){ 
  Row row = sh2.createRow(rownum);
  for (int cellnum = 1; cellnum <= object.getNum_columns()-1; cellnum++) {
   valor = object.getMetadata().get("columna"+cellnum); 
   Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum-1); 
   cell.setCellValue(valor);
  }
 }
 Row row = sh2.createRow(rownum+1);
 for (int cellnum = 1; cellnum <= object.getNum_columns(); cellnum++) {
  String valor = this.getMethod(object.getResponse().get(rownum), "" + cellnum);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum-1);
  String address = new CellReference(cell).formatAsString();
  cell.setCellValue(valor);
 }
}
```

how can I create another tab when limit size reach the value 1048576 or how can I continue writing in the same sheet maybe to use the file in another office?thank you.

Comment: you can take a counter and if it reaches the value, you create a new sheet and continue to write there. you will then have to be careful, because the row counter should be 0 but your data counter has to increase consistently

Comment: As per [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), that is the max limit. If you still want more rows, probably want to use `csv` type?